# Impacts on deleting FKs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jpa

So, I have a table with around 1.2 million records (`table A`) and another with around 5 million (`table B`). `Table A` has a one-to-many relation with table B. Sometimes a record on `table B` will have a reference on `table A`, sometimes it won't.

Inserting records that have that reference is taking a lot of time, around 5-6 seconds (when there's no reference is less than one second).

I've done a lot of research on it, about indexes and foreign keys and triggers. I saw that a lot people recommended deleting the FKs, inserting and restoring them. But I'm not sure this will help me because it's not a bulk insert. My sole doubt right now is:

what will be the practical impacts on deleting all FKs on both tables?

Comment: Inconsistent data?

Comment: have you looked at the execution plan? Or are you just guessing? Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: What do the table schemas look like? What indexes are there on the tables?

Comment: I'm not a DBA. This task just happened to be assigned to me. I didn't know anything about execution plan. I look it up and I'm going to investigate more. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Regarding the data, I don't think it has inconsistencies. Thing were fine about a month ago. And there some indexes on the tables, mostly on the PKs and some date columns.